# How to define the potential energy, and conservative forces?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, potential-energy, conservative-field

I understand that there are multiple questions under this name, but as far as I have seen, none of them answers what I am about to ask. If you came across a duplicate, please feel free to share the link.

I am confused about the definition of potential energy and conservative systems.
Starting from the literal meaning, in conservative systems, total mechanical energy is conserved: $$0=\frac d {dt}E=\frac d {dt}T+\frac d {dt}U=m\dot r\ddot r +\frac d {dt}U\quad\Rightarrow\quad F\dot r\ dt=dU\quad\Rightarrow\quad \int F\ d r =U$$

But, this requires us to have a definition of what mechanical energy is. Without explicitly using that definition, let's do the same thing for the total energy of the system, where I will denote the energy lost or added to the system by non-conservative forces with $N$, and the conservative with $U$: $$0=\frac d {dt}E =\frac d {dt}T+\frac d {dt} U+\frac d{dt} N= m\dot r\ddot r +\frac d{dt} U+\frac d {dt} N=m\dot r \ddot r+\frac d{dt} (U+N)\quad\Rightarrow\quad (U+N)=\int F\ dr$$

We achieve the same relationship, we might as well define $(U+N)$ as the conservative field instead of $U$.

Looking at the work-kinetic energy theorem, we get:
$$\Delta T=W=W^\text{conservative}+W^\text{non} = \int F^\text{conservative}\ dr +\int F^\text{non}\ dr=\Delta U +\int F^\text{non}\ dr$$

What I understand from here is that the cause of the change in kinetic energy of the object in a given system and chosen frame is due to both conservative and nonconservative forces by the same relationship.

I know that energy by the nonconservative forces mostly dissipate into heat or deformation and are therefore work-wise useless in a system, but I also don't see the direct use of the potential energy: Aren't both non-conservative and conservative forces "visible" by their effect on the velocity of the object? Then since they both are connected to $T$ by the same relationship, what exactly is the mathematical difference between a conservative and a non-conservative force, mechanical and total energy, and what exactly is the potential energy?

I am aware of the argument that integrating non-conservative forces over a closed path is non-zero, therefore they are non-conservative, but in that case, in a system where the object experiences both conservative and non-conservative forces, assuming we don't have a definition for conservativeness, the integral over the total force is going to be again non-zero; how do we define in this case a conservative force, do we need to observe the forces seperate from each other? Is the fundamental assumption for the definition of conservative forces, the linear superposition of forces?

I am sorry if my question is formulated chaotic and unstructured, I am very confused about this.

Comment: This is too unclear and confused. Do you know the definitions, in the context of multi-particle system, of 1) potential energy, 2) conservative forces? Maybe finding and understanding those will answer you questions?

Comment: @gluon Please ask only one question per post. As it stands, it is very difficult to understand what specific question you want answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so, lots of questions.
How I like to define the various types of mechanical energies goes something like this. From the point you have defined position, velocity, acceleration, mass, momentum and whatnot, you start to wonder how you may alter the trajectory of a body by exerting a force along it. This naturally leads you to consider the quantity $$W=\int_C F\cdot ds$$ that we call the work done by force $F$ along the path $C$. By changing variable we can write this quantity as $$W=\int_{v_i}^{v_f} mv \,dv=\frac{1}{2}mv^2 |_{v_i}^{v_f}$$
This is what allows us to define $T:=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$, because it is a quantity related to the inicial and final states of the system; it is path independent, and as such we may associate it with the system non-ambiguously, in the same way we do with position, velocity, momentum, etc...
Now, as for the case with potential energy, this is a trend we started to notice on systems, in which the work around a closed path was always zero for any path. A known result of calculus then allows us to write, for these kinds of forces, $$F=-\nabla V$$ Now why the minus sign? Because it results in being able to define mechanical energy in a suitable way $$W=\int_C -\nabla V \cdot ds= V_i-V_f=T_f-T_i$$
So you see because of the minus sign, we can rearrange thinks to get a sum which is equal at the endpoints of the path; it is conserved, and we call it $E=T+V$, the mechanical energy.

Then, getting around to your questions

> Aren't both non-conservative and conservative forces "visible" by their effect on the velocity of the object? Then since they both are connected to T
> by the same relationship, what exactly is the mathematical difference between a conservative and a non-conservative force, mechanical and total energy, and what exactly is the potential energy?

Yes, that's correct, both conservative and non-conservative forces will contribute to the work done. But the mathematical difference is still as clear as day. One of them depends on the path, the one doesn't. Of course if you start with a general force and do some work with it around a closed path and the work isn't zero, then you can't define a potential energy (there are generalizations of it that you can define in some situations, like generalized potentials, but that's another story) and you can't talk about some decomposition of your force in conservative + non-conservative components. What you can do is start with that supposition and see where it leads you, but from a general non-conservative force you can't say anything like that.

> I am aware of the argument that integrating non-conservative forces over a closed path is non-zero, therefore they are non-conservative, but in that case, in a system where the object experiences both conservative and non-conservative forces, assuming we don't have a definition for conservativeness, the integral over the total force is going to be again non-zero; how do we define in this case a conservative force, do we need to observe the forces seperate from each other? Is the fundamental assumption for the definition of conservative forces, the linear superposition of forces?

Yes, that's what we need to do. Take for example the gravitational force; you have to make sure that drag, friction and other non-conservative forces are negligible in order to state that it is conservative. Then you can build a model on that observation and test it. Of course having a model of the non-conservative forces at play will also help to "eliminate the noise". I don't know what you mean by your last sentence, but I hope this sheds some light

Answer (score 1):

"this requires us to have a definition of what mechanical energy is"

You just defined it in the line above. Mechanical energy is the sum of kinetic and potential energy, plus some constant (the arbitrarily selected zero of potential energy), which for a system with only conservative forces you expressed with:

$$\frac d {dt}E=\frac d {dt}T+\frac d {dt}U$$

Potential energy is that quantity whose change is equal and opposite that of kinetic energy for a system with only conservative forces, which you expressed with:

$$0 = \frac d {dt}T+\frac d {dt}U$$

Define system kinetic energy, and you're done - everything non-arbitrary is fully defined in terms of measurable observables. You have the special case of one point mass in your definition, which is fine, but we could generalize with:

$$T = 0.5\Sigma( m_i v_i^2 + I_i\omega_i^2)$$

---

If you want to include the possibility of non-conservative forces, add thermal internal energy.

$$dE = dT + dU + dQ$$

apply conservation of energy as before:

$$ 0 = dT + dU + dQ $$

As before

$$T = 0.5\Sigma( m_i v_i^2 + I_i\omega_i^2)$$

Given temperatures $\tau_i$ and specific heats $C_i$, for constant masses $m_i$,

$$dQ = \Sigma m_iC_id\tau_i$$

Comment: but here, you use potential energy to define mechanical energy. and then you use conservative forces to define potential energy. and conservative forces are defined as the forces that conserve mechanical energy over time. so it's very cylical

Comment: @gluon I used this because you specified conservative systems. If you want to include non-conservative forces, then we add a third unknown and a third equation. I'll edit the above answer since it's inconvenient to put it in a comment.